# How to loop through the columns and create different plots?

Tags: r, for-loop, plot, graphics, scatter-plot

I have a dataframe "A" with samples as rows and Genes as columns with gene expression values (RPKM).

```
        Gene1   Gene2           Gene3        Gene4        Gene5    Gene6
Sample1 0.02   0.038798682  0.1423662   2.778587067 0.471403939 18.93687655
Sample2 0      0.059227225  0.208765213 0.818810739 0.353671882 1.379027685
Sample3 0      0.052116384  0.230437735 2.535040249 0.504061015 9.773089223
Sample4 0.06   0.199264618  0.261100548 2.516963635 0.63659138  11.01441624
Sample5 0      0.123521916  0.273330986 2.751309388 0.623572499 34.0563519
Sample6 0      0.128767634  0.263491811 2.882878373 0.359322715 13.02402045
Sample7 0      0.080097356  0.234511372 3.568192768 0.386217698 9.068928569
Sample8 0      0.017421323  0.247775683 5.109428797 0.068760572 15.7490551
Sample9 0      2.10281137   0.401582013 8.202902242 0.140596724 60.25989178
```

To make a scatter plot showing correlation between Gene1 vs Gene5 and Gene6 I used following code:

```
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
pdf("Gene1.pdf")
A %>% 
  gather(key = variable, value = values, Gene5:Gene6) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Gene1, values)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  facet_grid(. ~ variable, scales = "free_x") + 
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE) + 
  scale_y_continuous(trans = "log2", labels = NULL, breaks = NULL) + 
  scale_x_continuous(trans = "log2", labels = NULL, breaks = NULL)
dev.off()
```

I also want to plot for

```
Gene2 vs Gene5 and Gene6
Gene3 vs Gene5 and Gene6
Gene4 vs Gene5 and Gene6
```

Ofcourse I can replace `Gene1` in the code with other Gene to plot. But instead of manual replacement I would like to make a loop so that from Gene1 to Gene4 plots against Gene5 and Gene6 with different plots each saved in pdf with respective gene names.

Based on request this is an Update about `dput(A)`:

```
structure(list(Gene1 = c(0.02, 0, 0, 0.06, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Gene2 = c(0.038798682, 
0.059227225, 0.052116384, 0.199264618, 0.123521916, 0.128767634, 
0.080097356, 0.017421323, 2.10281137), Gene3 = c(0.1423662, 0.208765213, 
0.230437735, 0.261100548, 0.273330986, 0.263491811, 0.234511372, 
0.247775683, 0.401582013), Gene4 = c(2.778587067, 0.818810739, 
2.535040249, 2.516963635, 2.751309388, 2.882878373, 3.568192768, 
5.109428797, 8.202902242), Gene5 = c(0.471403939, 0.353671882, 
0.504061015, 0.63659138, 0.623572499, 0.359322715, 0.386217698, 
0.068760572, 0.140596724), Gene6 = c(18.93687655, 1.379027685, 
9.773089223, 11.01441624, 34.0563519, 13.02402045, 9.068928569, 
15.7490551, 60.25989178)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("Sample1", 
"Sample2", "Sample3", "Sample4", "Sample5", "Sample6", "Sample7", 
"Sample8", "Sample9"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would a loop work for you? I haven't tested (since you don't have the data as dput()), so may need some cleanup.

```
cols <- colnames(A)
cols <- cols[!cols %in% c("Gene5", "Gene6")]
for(i in cols){
    name <- paste(i, ".pdf", sep = "")
    id <- which(colnames(A) == i)
    # add a new column - this is the one accepting the "rotating" gene input
    A$Gene <- A[,id]

p <- A %>% 
        select(Gene, Gene5, Gene6) %>%
        gather(variable, values, Gene5:Gene6) %>% 
        ggplot(aes(Gene, values)) + 
        geom_point() + 
        facet_grid(. ~ variable, scales = "free_x") + 
        geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE) + 
        scale_y_continuous(trans = "log2", labels = NULL, breaks = NULL) + 
        scale_x_continuous(i, trans = "log2", labels = NULL, breaks = NULL)

    pdf(name)
    print(p)

     dev.off()
        }
```

Comment: nope this didn't work. And in for loop I don't want to mention names of Gene1 to Gene4.

Comment: Can you post the data as dput(A)? And what do you mean by not wanting to mention names? What would work better for you?

Comment: What I mean is in this data I need Gene1 to Gene4 against Gene5 and Gene6 as I mentioned in the question. But in my original data I have more than 50 genes which I need plot against Gene5 and Gene6

Comment: I made an edit to the answer - had a typo in the code. Give it another try? And if that doesn't work - please run dput(A) in R and post the output here, so that I can read it in easily and test the code :-)

Comment: Are all the 50 genes named as GeneX?

Comment: No, not all genes are named as GeneX....All genes are with different names.

Comment: I meant whether they're all called Gene1, Gene2, Gene3, ...Gene50, and so on :-) Doesn't matter now - I update the loop to use all columns that aren't Gene5 and Gene6. See if that works.

Comment: no didn't work. On ur request I posted dput(A) in the question.

Comment: I fixed up a couple more things and reran with your data - looks good now.

Answer (score 2):

if you need an explicit for loop:

```
for (gene in paste0("Gene",1:4)){
 a= A %>% 
    gather(key = variable, value = values, Gene5:Gene6) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(get(gene), values)) + 
    geom_point() + 
    facet_grid(. ~ variable, scales = "free_x") + 
    geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE) + 
    scale_y_continuous(trans = "log2", labels = NULL, breaks = NULL) + 
    scale_x_continuous(trans = "log2", labels = NULL, breaks = NULL)

    print(a)

}
```

Comment: What if columns Gene1 to Gene4 are named with different names like TGF, DGTH, HJUY, DSER.

Comment: put all the names you want in a vector. eg `s= c('TGF', 'DGTH', 'HJUY', 'DSER')` and now do `for(gene in s){….}`

Comment: Thank you very much !! but u didn't show how to save the plots as pdfs

Comment: Everything else remains the same. I know you could do that. just include the pdf part in the loop ie `pdf(gene)` etc etc